# Generic KDTree in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I would like to have a generic KDTree implementation in C++ that can hold any kind of *positionable* object. Such objects have a 2D position.

Unfortunately. Positionable classes could have different ways of getting the position.

- Getters `getX()` and `getY()`
- std::pair<double, double>
- sf::Vector2f
- ...

What would be the proper way to wrap such classes into my KDTree?

My Tree is composed of nodes such as:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    int id;
    T element;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(T element) : element(element), left(NULL), right(NULL)
    {
        static int id = 0;
        this->id = id++;
    }
};
```

Somehow I would like to have a generic getter to the position of `T element`.

One possible solution is to define a positionable interface:

```
struct KDTreeElement {
    virtual getX() = 0;
    virtual getY() = 0;
}
```

The con of this method is that the positionable element must know the KDTree library

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the design rationale of [boost geometry](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/design.html) for a solution to this problem. The methodology boils down to these steps:

1. Declare a class template that extracts position information from a type, e.g.

   ```
   template <class Geometry>
   struct Position;
   ```
2. To make your kd Tree usable with a new type, say `MyAwesome2dPoint`, specialize this template for it. In the specialization you can use the type's method of getting the position:

   ```
   template <>
   struct Position<MyAwesome2dPoint>
   {
       static float getX(MyAwesome2dPoint const& p) { return p.x; }
       static float getY(MyAwesome2dPoint const& p) { return p.y; } 
   }
   ```
3. Use this type system in your kd tree, i.e. instead of directly accessing positions, go through the `Position` class:

   ```
   class KdTree 
   {
       template <class PointType>
       auto contains(PointType const& g)
       {
           // Geometric properties are accessed through the traits system.
           return contains_impl(
               Position<PointType>::getX(g), 
               Position<PointType>::getY(g));
       }
   }
   ```
4. For extra credit, create a concept to avoid the weird compilation errors when using a type that hasn't been configured to work with your library:

   ```
   template <class G>
   concept Positionable = requires (G g) { 
       Position<G>::getX() + Position<G>::getY(); 
   }; 

   // So now you can explicitly operate on such types
   template <Positionable G>
   auto contains(G const& g)
   {
   }
   ```

No inheritance, no virtuals, no modifications to existing types. Just create a layer that can be specialized for everyone (even C types) and you're good to go. Concepts will save your life when abstracting even further, e.g. boost geometry generalizes to `N` dimensions, different coordinate systems and more.

Comment: Whooh ! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for :)